# I got the error when I make a branch with the specified data in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I would like to make a branch in Python API of CPLEX with the specified data at each node but I got an error in my code. The problem is related to the **indexmax**.
Error:

```
"in method 'intArray___setitem__', argument 3 of type 'int'".
```

Code:

```
class CB6Callback(CPX_CB.BranchCallback):
def __call__(self):
       objval   = self.get_objective_value()
       Xval     = self.get_values()
       ...
       if not Df7.empty:                  
              colYTest = Df7.YTest
              indexmax = colYTest.idxmax()
              xj_lo = floor(Xval[indexmax])
              self.make_branch(objval, variables=[(indexmax, "L", xj_lo +1)], 
                                                   node_data=(indexmax, xj_lo, "UP"))
              self.make_branch(objval, variables=[(indexmax, "U", xj_lo)],
                                                   node_data=(indexmax, xj_lo, "DOWN"))
```

Comment: I think more info would be helpful. The stacktrace is probably much bigger containing useful info. Furthermore, the code shown is very incomplete. If `floor` is python's, i would expect an `int` and this should be good. If `floor` is numpy's howewer, the return can be of type `float` and will likely induce problems with low-level c-interfaces. You see i'm only guessing without ever having touched this part of cplex, but i would recommend printing out the *type* information of your arguments and check against the arguments as documented. C-types vs. Python-types have bitten me more than once.

Comment: Thank you @sascha. The problem is related to **indexmax** . I checked the type of **indexmax** it was numpy.int64 not float. How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment from OP, this should suffice:

```python
x = np.int64(3)
print(type(x))
# <class 'numpy.int64'>

y = x.item()   # !!!
print(type(y))
# <class 'int'>
```

See [numpy.ndarray.item¶](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html)

(From my experience, usage of np-types is not handled well by cplex: e.g. as factors in `SparsePair` *vals*)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm CPLEX Python API does not handle numpy numeric types, either numpy integer types or float types.
Calling Python conversion function (e.g. int(x) or float(z) ) should work.